# Spring boot stops right after "Started <app_name> in X seconds (JVM running for Y)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am using Eclipse 14.4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.3. I've loaded "Spring Tools 3" and a Lombok plugin.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The TestApplication class:

```
package com.test.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the DemoController class:

```
package com.test.test.controller;

//Importing required classes
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
 
// Annotation
@Controller
 
// Class
public class DemoController {
 
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
 
    // Method
    public String helloWorld()
    {
 
        // Print statement
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

To run the program, I right-click on it and select Run As --> Java Application. From the "Select Java Application" popup that's generated, I select "TestApplication - com.test.test".

Spring Boot loads and runs until it gets to the final line of code below, after which nothing happens.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-02-12 16:21:21.779  INFO 166442 --- [           main] com.test.test.TestApplication            : Starting TestApplication using Java 13.0.2 on ubuntu with PID 166442 (/home/oleh/Downloads/test/target/classes started by oleh in /home/oleh/Downloads/test)
2022-02-12 16:21:21.849  INFO 166442 --- [           main] com.test.test.TestApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-12 16:21:58.814  INFO 166442 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2022-02-12 16:21:59.033  INFO 166442 --- [           main] com.test.test.TestApplication            : Started TestApplication in 43.693 seconds (JVM running for 51.954)
```

If I open a web browser and search the localhost:8080 URL, I'm given an error that says "Whitelable Error Page".

I've tried updating Maven dependencies and cleaning the project. I've also tried many variations of this project, all of which ended the same way. I'm not sure what to verify and debug because the console does not print any errors.

Can anyone help explain what is missing for the browser window to open and "Hello World!" to be displayed on it?

Many thanks.

Comment: The fact that when you load http://localhost:8080 and it is serving a page saying "Whitelabel Error Page" is a sign that the server process is running. The log shown is what I typically expect after starting up the server, but the lack of error/stack traces is a concern. I would explore any logs directory and check if is there perhaps some configuration that is writing the errors out into a log file instead of dumping it in console.

Comment: What happens when you request the URL your controller is mapped to?

Answer (score 1):

Please try localhost:8080/hello

Comment: I was adjusting Maven dependencies and nothing was working. But indeed, the issue was simply not typing the @RequestMapping value in the URL. Clearly I am new at this. Thank you for taking the time to look through my problem.